# How to delete all the lines in a UNIX file except first and last line?

Tags: bash, shell-script

I want to keep only header and trailer records in a UNIX file.

Comment: What have you tried? What editor/commandline-program have you been using. What didn't work?

Comment: Filter first and last lines instead of deleting others!

Comment: `sed '2,$d' filename`

Answer (score 11):

With sed:

```
sed -n '1p;$p' file
```

Suppress automatic printing of pattern space (`-n`) but print first (`1p`) and last line (`$p`) of pattern space.

If you want to edit your file "in place" use sed's option `-i`.

Answer (score 5):

Use `head` and `tail`, one after another:

```
head -n 1 file.txt; tail -n 1 file.txt
```

Running `tail` if `head` succeeds:

```
head -n 1 file.txt && tail -n 1 file.txt
```

**Example:**

```
% cat file.txt 
foo
spam
egg
bar


% head -n 1 file.txt; tail -n 1 file.txt
foo
bar

% head -n 1 file.txt && tail -n 1 file.txt
foo
bar
```